# Importing dataset.mnist

Tags: python, dataset, mnist

I am following a [deep learning tutorial book in Japanese](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117584/) and it is using MNIST for its handwritten images. It has the code `from dataset.mnist import load_dataset`, and when I tried it, it did not work, gave an error saying no such module named `dataset.mnist`. I have downloaded the modules `dataset` and `mnist` individually using `pip`. The book recommended to use Anaconda, but I have tried it to no success.

How can I use the module `dataset.mnist`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question I want to ask you is which deep learning framework are you working with for solving your problem. 
There are many deep learning frameworks. PyTorch, Tensorflow, and Keras are examples of such frameworks.

1) If you are working with PyTorch framework then you should import the torch framework using the command.

```
import torch
```

and then you can import MNIST dataset using the command

```
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
```

2) For Keras framework use the following commands for importing MNIST dataset.

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

NOTE: This can be written as well for better understanding of your problem.

```
import keras
from keras.datasets as datasets
```

and then you can import MNIST dataset using the`datasets` which is an alias of `keras.datasets`
Similarly, you can import MNIST dataset in other frameworks as well.

Hope this will be of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @SauravRai's Answer

For **tensorflow** :

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
input_data.read_data_sets('my/directory')
```